# JourneyBuilder Automation Audience and Exit

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a journey (let's call it 'No Store') that is taking an audience from an automation that is run daily.

However, that audience will fluctuate in size based upon the query that is part of the automation.

To provide context: I have 2 journeys.  No Store is for users that have not created an online store and Yes Store is for users that have created one.

The question is -- if a subscriber gets and email in the No Store journey and immediately goes and creates a store - will their subscriber_key not being in the audience after the first email remove them from the journey?  Or will they remain in the No Store Journey?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All users will remain in a journey the moment they enter irrespective of whether they qualify for another journey or not.

### Solution to kicking out subscribers in the middle of the No Store Journey if they qualify for the Yes Store Journey

If you wish to kick them out of the No Store Journey if they qualify for Yes Store Journey, then this might help you.

It is up to the marketing cloud user to implement checks throughout the journeys to identify if they qualify for another journey so you can exit them at specific points in a journey.

### In your No Store Journey:

You can link up the Yes Store Journey Data Extension audience that will contain a list of all the subscribers in that journey that will become visible to you in the No Store Journey Contact Data Filter as long as your relationships in data designer are correct.

You can then add an extra filter at specific points in the journey, maybe prior to each main activity (eg; Send Email Activity).

You can do something like is `No Store Journey > Id = Yes Store Journey > Id`

If this evaluates to `False`, then the user will proceed in the No Store Journey.

If `True`, you can have them exit the journey early as they do exist in the Yes Store Journey Audience now as they have qualified for having a store.

Comment: If my `Entry Source` is an `Automation Audience` is it possible to do any filtering within the Journey Builder?  Or would I just add a `Filter` within the automation studio?

Comment: You can perform filters at a query level or a journey level it really just depends when those filters need to occur based on the scenario your dealing with, if you need to filter inside a journey just add a decision split activity or do it at the entry event level, if not then do it at the automation query level.

Answer (score 0):

They will remain in the running journey until completed and data will be available when using event data as this always represents the state the time they entered the journey.